# Which alternative analysis to a 2-factor ANOVA when having 2 independent variables and one dependent?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova

So, I have a dataset where I need to test the relationship between 2 independent **qualitative** variables and one dependent **quantitative** variable.

I wanted to use 2-way ANOVA but my independent variable doesn't follow a normal distribution nor does homoscedasticity.

Any suggestions? I'm not a statistician, just doing some research so any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you said "my independent variable doesn't follow a normal distribution" did you mean "dependent variable"? Also, you don't need to have normality overall, just within each of ultimate classes (e.g., within each of the 4 classes with 2 x 2 categorical predictors).